# in ksh/grep: finding a pattern not after the comment marker

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, ksh

I'm trying to figure the best way to grep for a string that isn't after a comment delimiter.  Consider the following file "test_file":

```
#test this 1
    #test this 2
test this 3
    test this 4
   # my test this 5
# my test this 6
my test this 7
   my test this 8
test this 9 # my test this 9
this 10 # my test this 10
```

and I want to grep for "test", but only return lines 3, 4, 7, 8, and 9.

I was able to get this result with the following:

```
sed -e 's/^[ ]*//' test_file | grep -n "^[^#]*test"

3:test this 3
4:test this 4
7:my test this 7
8:my test this 8
9:test this 9 # my test this 9
```

but I'm not sure how it works, and so I'm worried that it might have unexpected consequences.  adding a dot before the asterisk, which I thought might be the way to do it, doesn't work:

```
sed -e 's/^[ ]*//' test_file | grep -n "^[^#].*test"

7:my test this 7
8:my test this 8
9:test this 9 # my test this 9
10:this 10 # my test this 10
```

another solution I've been able to do was simply to use sed to remove all text after the pound sign and grep for "test", which is straightforward and functional.  but I'm curious -- how does the former `grep -n "^[^#]*test"` work, and would it be what i want?

Comment: So which lines do you want? 3, 4, 5, 8, 9?

Comment: Just so you know. The `sed` statement is deleting any leading spaces and the `grep` is looking for a line that starts with character that's not a `#` (zero-or-more) followed by the word `test`.

Comment: @skamazin ahhh I understand now what it was doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep for lines that contain "test" with no `#` characters before it on the line:

```
grep -n '^[^#]*test'
```

That matches the start of the line (`^`), followed by any number of characters that *aren't* a '#' (`[^#]*`), followed by "test".

Comment: Ahhh that makes so much sense. Don't know why my brain couldn't parse what it was saying. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using grep only:

```
grep -n '^[^#]*test' file
3:test this 3
4:    test this 4
7:my test this 7
8:   my test this 8
9:test this 9 # my test this 9
```